# .Net regex not replacing correctly

Tags: c#, regex

### Background

I am trying to do some regex matching and replacing, but for some reason the replacement isn't correct in .NET.

*Regex pattern* - `"^.*?/rebate/?$"`

*Input string* - `"/my-tax/rebate"`

*Replacement string* - `"/new-path/rebate"`

Basically, if the word '*rebate*' is seen in a string, the input string needs to be replaced entirely by the replacement string.

### Problem

If I create a regex with the pattern and execute

```
patternMatch.Pattern.Replace("/my-tax/rebate", "/new-path/rebate")
```

I get *`/my-tax/new-path/rebate`*, which isn't correct.

But, if I execute -

`new Regex(@"^.*?/rebate/?$").Replace("/my-tax/rebate", "/new-path/rebate")`, 
the result is correct - *`/new-path/rebate`*

Why is that?

`patternMatch` is an object with two properties - one `Pattern` (which is the Regex Pattern) and another one is `TargetPath` (which is the replacement string). In this example, I am only using the pattern property.

`patternMatch.Pattern` on debugging is

[image]

Here are the results during run time-

[image]

Comment: what is patternMatch.Pattern.Replace? Is it a public API?

Comment: It is function of System.Text.RegularExpressions. `public string Replace(string input, string replacement)`

Comment: Your regex that works is different from the one that doesn't work. (you have an extra / at the end) Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by `if the word 'rebate' is seen in a string, the input string needs to be replaced entirely by the replacement string`? So `xxxx/xxxx/rebate` will become `/new-path/rebate`?

Comment: @unlimit - yes, that's pretty much it. Replace the whole string if the match is found.

Comment: @rene - I don't see any extra '/'?

Comment: @NomadTraveler compare `"^.*?/rebate/?$"` with `@"^.*?/rebate?$"` and count the number of `/` you see...

Comment: @rene: You are right about the extra `/` of course; but the pattern(s) work regardless, which is the greater confusion IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply wrongly using the function. I'm not sure how you are getting `/my-tax/new-path/rebate` since it is giving me an error on ideone.com (Maybe you have a regex named `Pattern`?).

Anyway, you shouldn't have any issues with using the function like this:

```
patternMatch.Replace("/my-tax/rebate", "/new-path/rebate");
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/PzoQBJ)

Comment: @NomadTraveler How are you generating `patternMatch.Pattern`? Could you show more of the code please?

Comment: Posted a bit more info, @jerry

Comment: @NomadTraveler In what software are you doing this (if it's ok to ask)?

Comment: @NomadTraveler I don't mean the language. I mean like, Visual Studio? From where do you get those results during runtime and debug traces?

Answer (score 0):

A number of points in your question are incorrect.  The regex *is* replacing correctly.

Per @XiaoguangQiao's comment, what is `patternMatch.Pattern.Replace`?  Your example...

```
var patternMatch = new Regex("^.*?/rebate/?$");
patternMatch.Pattern.Replace("/my-tax/rebate", "/new-path/rebate");
```

...errors with the message...

> 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' does not contain a definition for 'Pattern' and no extension method 'Pattern' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' could be found

...when I throw it into a quick LINQPad 4 query (set to *C# Statement(s)*).

`pattern` is a `private string` *field* of `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`; and `patternMatch.Replace("/my-tax/rebate", "/new-path/rebate")` - which I expect is what you meant - yields the correct result (`"/new-path/rebate"`) rather than the incorrect result you said you get (`"/my-tax/new-path/rebate"`).

Otherwise your pattern(s) (i.e. with and without the extra `/` that @rene pointed out) is fine for the input (`"/my-tax/rebate"`) and replacement (`"/new-path/rebate"`) you initially outline - insofar as they match and yield the result you want.  You can check this outside your code in quick fiddles [with the extra `/`](http://fiddle.re/35w8p) and [without the extra `/`](http://fiddle.re/ccqab).

Comment: patternMatch.Pattern is the regex object name. Please check the attached image in the question.

Comment: @NomadTraveler: Periods are not legal in C# variable names - just underscores, letters, and digits. Regardless, you would essentially have `patternMatch.Replace("/my-tax/rebate", "/new-path/rebate")`, which works, with a different variable name - an immaterial difference.

Comment: My bad. It isn't object name. patternMatch is an object with two properties - one Pattern (which is the Regex Pattern) and another one is TargetPath (which is the replacement string). In this example, I am only using the pattern property. Apologize for all the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Use String.Replace Method.

str.replace("rebate","new-path/rebate")

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Two problems: 1) `str.Replace` not `str.replace` 2) Regardless, this yields the wrong result - `/my-tax/new-path/rebate` as demonstrated by `var str = "/my-tax/rebate";  Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("rebate","new-path/rebate"));`.